# How to receive an uploaded file inside a form flow

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

I wonder how to receive an uploaded file inside a Microsoft Bot Framework FormFlow.

I wish my users could upload a file (i.e. a photo of their documenti ID) after some questions in order to save in our CRM.

I well know is possible to send attachments while regular conversations to manage inside `public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)` but not clear how to manage the process while inside a FormFlow dialog in the middle of some other questions.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Bot Receive attachments from user using FormFlow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41853523/microsoft-bot-receive-attachments-from-user-using-formflow)

Answer (score 0):

Activity Attachments can't be handled in the FormFlow.
The reason for this is that the FormDialog used by the FormBuilder only passes the Text of the Activity to the Fields.

```
public async Task MessageReceived(IDialogContext context, 
        IAwaitable<Connector.IMessageActivity> toBot)
        {
            try
            {
                var toBotText = (toBot != null ? (await toBot).Text : null);
                var stepInput = toBotText == null ? "" : toBotText.Trim();
                //rest of the method.
```

Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/FormFlow/FormDialog.cs

There is only one way you can do this in your form and that is by making your user send you the URL of the image/file.

Another option is to ask the user if he wants to upload something as the last question in you form (Boolean property) and then check this in the ResumeAfterForm method. If the value is true you start a special dialog that asks for the image/file. That way you can easily extract the attachments from the message.