# How to make user send image attachment in botframework

Tags: c#, botframework

```
[Serializable]
public class VehicleForm
{
    [Prompt("When did this happen")]
    public DateTime LossDate { get; set; }

    [Prompt("Please upload proof image")]
    public byte Picture { get; set; }
```

I want a user to be able to include image when filling a form in bot framework. I declared the picture field as byte but didn't work when i upload image. Is this possible to achieve? if yes please can anyone brief me on how to go about it?. Thanks

Comment: Did you check the sample in Botbuilder's github page? https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-ReceiveAttachment

Comment: yes i did, is there a way i can implement it in Forms?

Comment: Need to see the details of your use case, so I don't know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41853523/microsoft-bot-receive-attachments-from-user-using-formflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [sample in the SDK Repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/Microsoft.Bot.Sample.FormFlowAttachmentsBot) for doing exactly this.

From the sample it appears you need to use the `AwaitableAttachment` type, take a look at the [`ImagesForm`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/Microsoft.Bot.Sample.FormFlowAttachmentsBot/ImagesForm.cs):

```
// Attachment field has no validation - any attachment would work
public AwaitableAttachment BestImage;

// Attachment field is optional - validation is done through AttachmentContentTypeValidator usage
[Optional]
[AttachmentContentTypeValidator(ContentType = "png")]
public AwaitableAttachment SecondaryImage;
```