# Bot Framework - Handling user sent images in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, botframework

I can't find any way to handle the images sent by the user to my Bot. Is there any way to get the images?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40717552/is-there-a-way-to-accept-file-as-an-attachment-in-bot-framework) which is similar, but for C#, and I am working in node.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user attaches something to a message, it will be in the `results.response` array. You can access the first attachment with a simple `results.response[0]`. This object has `contentType` and `contentUrl` properties, which you can use to do whatever you need to do.

To insure you get an image, you can prompt the user to attach something using [builder.Prompts.attachment](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.prompts.html#attachment). Of course they could attach any sort of file to their message, from a text file to a .zip, so you need to check that it's an appropriate file type.

```
bot.dialog('/prompts', [
    function (session) {
        builder.Prompts.attachment(session, "Send me a file!");
    },
    function (session, results) {
        var firstAttachment = results.response[0],
            msg = new builder.Message(session)
                .text("You sent a file of type %s and named %s",
                      firstAttachment.contentType, firstAttachment.name);
        msg.addAttachment(attachment);
        session.endDialog(msg);
    }
})
```

Comment: To sum up to Mike's response, see the ReceiveAttachment node.js sample

Comment: Yes, which is available [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-ReceiveAttachment).

Comment: Oops! Thanks Mike, I forgot to paste the link